# Discord.py assistance - How does the library forcibly call an asynchronous command function?

Tags: function, api, discord.py, python-decorators

I have used many discord API wrappers, but as an experienced python developer, unfortunately I somehow still do not understand how a command gets called!

```
@client.command()
async demo(ctx):
    channel = ctx.channel
    await channel.send(f'Demonstration')
```

Above a command has been created (function) and it is placed after its decorator `@client.command()`
To my understanding, the decorator is in a way, a "check" performed before running the function (demo) but I do not understand how the discord.py library seemingly "calls" the demo function.....?? Is there some form of short/long polling system in the local imported discord.py library which polls the discord API and receives a list of jobs/messages and checks these against the functions the user has created?

**I would love to know how this works as I dont understand what "calls" the functions that the user makes, and this would allow me to make my own wrapper for another similar social media platform! Many thanks in advance.**

I am trying to work out how functions created by the user are seemingly "called" by the discord.py library. I have worked with the discord.py wrapper and other API wrappers before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(See source code attached at the bottom of the answer)*

The `@bot.command()` decorator adds a command to the internal lists/mappings of commands stored in the Bot instance.

Whenever a message is received, this runs through `Bot.process_commands`. It can then look through every command stored to check if the message starts with one of them (prefix is checked beforehand). If it finds a match, then it can invoke it (the underlying callback is stored in the `Command` instance).

If you've ever overridden an `on_message` event and your commands stopped working, then this is why: that method is no longer being called, so it no longer tries to look through your commands to find a match.

This uses a `dictionary` to make it far more efficient - instead of having to iterate over every single command & alias available, it only has to check if the first letters of the message match anything at all.

---

The `commands.Command()` decorator used in Cogs works slightly different. This turns your function into a `Command` instance, and when adding a cog (using `Bot.add_cog()`) the library checks every attribute to see if any of them are `Command` instances.

---

#### References to source code

`GroupMixin.command()` (called when you use `@client.command()`): https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/24bdb44d54686448a336ea6d72b1bf8600ef7220/discord/ext/commands/core.py#L1493

As you can see, it calls `add_command()` internally to add it to the list of commands.

Adding commands (`GroupMixin.add_command()`): https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/24bdb44d54686448a336ea6d72b1bf8600ef7220/discord/ext/commands/core.py#L1315

`Bot.process_commands()`: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/discord/ext/commands/bot.py#L1360

You'll have to follow the chain - most of the processing actually happens in `get_context` which tries to create a `Context` instance out of the message: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/24bdb44d54686448a336ea6d72b1bf8600ef7220/discord/ext/commands/bot.py#L1231

`commands.Command()`: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/discord/ext/commands/core.py#L1745